# Blender keeps crashing at random. Problem with Action constraint?

Tags: animation, nla-editor, bone.constraints

My Blender keeps crashing at random intervals whenever I am in a project using two specific rigs I put together. Most of the time it's completely fine to use them, but other times it suddenly begins crashing again and again, and I can't find a pattern that causes this. My drivers are up to date.

My theory is that it is spamming the Action constraint for some reason, causing it to use too much memory and shutting down.

I do not know how to add a `.txt` file to this question, but here are some excerpts from the debug log:

`WARN (bke.anim_sys): C:\Users\blender\git\blender-v340\blender.git\source\blender\blenkernel\intern\anim_sys.c:3541 animsys_calculate_nla: NLA Eval: Stopgap for active action on NLA Stack - no strips case`

*There's 3 of these, not sure if relevant.*

```
Dependency cycle detected:
  OBRig Cano.001/TGT-JAW/BONE_CONSTRAINTS() depends on
  OBRig Cano.001/CTRL-MOUTH-CORNER.R/BONE_DONE() via 'Action'
  OBRig Cano.001/CTRL-MOUTH-CORNER.R/BONE_READY() via 'Ready -> Done'
  OBRig Cano.001/CTRL-MOUTH-CORNER.R/BONE_POSE_PARENT() via 'Pose -> Ready'
  OBRig Cano.001/MCH-INT-MOUTH-CORNER.R/BONE_DONE() via 'Parent Bone -> Child Bone'
  OBRig Cano.001/MCH-INT-MOUTH-CORNER.R/BONE_READY() via 'Ready -> Done'
  OBRig Cano.001/MCH-INT-MOUTH-CORNER.R/BONE_CONSTRAINTS() via 'Constraints -> Ready'
  OBRig Cano.001/MCH-MOUTH-CORNER.R/BONE_DONE() via 'Copy Transforms'
  OBRig Cano.001/MCH-MOUTH-CORNER.R/BONE_READY() via 'Ready -> Done'
  OBRig Cano.001/MCH-MOUTH-CORNER.R/BONE_POSE_PARENT() via 'Pose -> Ready'
  OBRig Cano.001/TGT-JAW/BONE_DONE() via 'Parent Bone -> Child Bone'
  OBRig Cano.001/TGT-JAW/BONE_READY() via 'Ready -> Done'
  OBRig Cano.001/TGT-JAW/BONE_CONSTRAINTS() via 'Constraints -> Ready'
```

This one is repeated once more, with the exact same thing written, followed by: **Detected 2 dependency cycles**

I see that there's a dependency cycle here, but it should be on all the rigs I made and it's only with these two the problems arrive. Then this keeps getting spammed, etc., etc. Most of the debug file is this:

```
do Action Constraint Action - Ob CameraShakify.v2_Camera.011_0 Pchan (null)
do Action Constraint Action - Ob CameraShakify.v2_Camera.012_0 Pchan (null)
do Action Constraint Action - Ob CameraShakify.v2_Camera.013_0 Pchan (null)
do Action Constraint Action-EyeBlink - Ob Rig Chase.001 Pchan CTRL-TWEAK-EYE-LOW03.R
do Action Constraint Action-EyeWide - Ob Rig Chase.001 Pchan CTRL-TWEAK-EYE-LOW03.R
do Action Constraint Action-EyeBlink - Ob Rig Chase.001 Pchan CTRL-TWEAK-EYE-LOW02.R
do Action Constraint Action-EyeWide - Ob Rig Chase.001 Pchan CTRL-TWEAK-EYE-LOW02.R
do Action Constraint Action-EyeBlink - Ob Rig Chase.001 Pchan CTRL-TWEAK-EYE-LOW01.R
do Action Constraint Action-EyeWide - Ob Rig Chase.001 Pchan CTRL-TWEAK-EYE-LOW01.R
do Action Constraint Action-EyeBlink - Ob Rig Chase.001 Pchan CTRL-TWEAK-EYE-UP03.R
do Action Constraint Action-EyeWide - Ob Rig Chase.001 Pchan CTRL-TWEAK-EYE-UP03.R
do Action Constraint Action-EyeBlink - Ob Rig Chase.001 Pchan CTRL-TWEAK-EYE-UP02.R
do Action Constraint Action-EyeWide - Ob Rig Chase.001 Pchan CTRL-TWEAK-EYE-UP02.R
do Action Constraint Action-EyeBlink - Ob Rig Chase.001 Pchan CTRL-TWEAK-EYE-UP01.R
do Action Constraint Action-EyeWide - Ob Rig Chase.001 Pchan CTRL-TWEAK-EYE-UP01.R
do Action Constraint Action-EyeBlink - Ob Rig Chase.001 Pchan CTRL-TWEAK-EYE-CORNER-OUT.R
do Action Constraint Action-EyeWide - Ob Rig Chase.001 Pchan CTRL-TWEAK-EYE-CORNER-OUT.R
do Action Constraint Action-EyeBlink - Ob Rig Chase.001 Pchan CTRL-TWEAK-EYE-CORNER.R
do Action Constraint Action-EyeWide - Ob Rig Chase.001 Pchan CTRL-TWEAK-EYE-CORNER.R
do Action Constraint Action-EyebrowRaise - Ob Rig Chase.001 Pchan TGT-EYEBROW01.L
do Action Constraint Action-EyebrowLower - Ob Rig Chase.001 Pchan TGT-EYEBROW01.L
do Action Constraint Action-EyeBlink - Ob Rig Chase.001 Pchan CTRL-TWEAK-EYE-LOW03.L
do Action Constraint Action-EyebrowRaise - Ob Rig Cano.001 Pchan TGT-EYEBROW04.L
do Action Constraint Action-EyeWide - Ob Rig Chase.001 Pchan CTRL-TWEAK-EYE-LOW03.L
do Action Constraint Action-EyebrowLower - Ob Rig Cano.001 Pchan TGT-EYEBROW04.L
```

*Even with a dependency cycle for the jaw bone, that doesn't explain why it is spamming the action for eyebrows and eyelids. Why is it happening? How do I fix it?*

When it crashes it says this:

```
Error   : EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION
Address : 0x00007FF6915BADEC
Module  : blender.exe
Thread  : 00005340
do Action Constraint Action-EyebrowRaise - Ob Rig Chase.001 Pchan TGT-EYEBROW04.L
do Action Constraint Action-EyebrowLower - Ob Rig Chase.001 Pchan TGT-EYEBROW04.L
do Action Constraint Action-EyebrowRaise - Ob Rig Chase.001 Pchan TGT-EYEBROW01.R
```

*And it repeats the entire Constraint Action thing once more for good measure.*

It also mentions `NLA Eval: Stopgap for active action on NLA Stack - no strips case` some more times. What is that?

I see the Shakify add-on appearing in the debug output from time to time. Could it be part of the problem?

Do you think the dependency cycle could be the problem?
The mouth bones are constrained to bones parented to the jaw bone so I can toggle them following or not following the jaw.

Comment: you should file a bug report to Blender with help->report a bug. This is not part of this site.

Comment: @Chris I'm not sure if this can be successfully accepted as a bug, since it is not happening with other rigs. You should be able to reproduce issue with a new file.

Comment: @Gaja you post a lot of text ... from quick view it sounds to me (I'm not an animator) as a rig  or action issue ... try to delete some NLA actions or part of your rig (mentioned in reports) to see what cause crashing so you can concentrate on that part ... or share your simplified file (delete all that doesn't participate on the issue).

Comment: Ok thank you, I will give it a try. I'm sorry if this was posted in the wrong place, I've only ever seen this forum through earlier troubleshooting and didn't know where else to go